# Convert camel case to snake case in a global manner

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to convert fields to be snake cased for use to map response from a rest call in dart?

Meaning I state in one place that I want mappings to occur in **snake_case** and not have to mention it for every model I create?

Looking for something similar to how we can achieve this via **ObjectMapper** and **PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE** in **Java**.

Making a rest call (which follows snake casing) in flutter and only able to map if I name the fields in snake cased format.

Tried the following which doesn't make a difference and end up with null values.

```
class FeatureResponse {
  @JsonValue("trending_posters") // tried this from json_annotation package
  List<Poster> trendingPosters;

  FeatureResponse({this.trendingPosters});

  factory FeatureResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => _$FeatureResponseFromJson(data);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FeatureResponseToJson(this);
}
```

Alternatively there is a package **dart_json_mapper** which assist with this snake case mapping.

But that conflicts with **json_annotation** package which am using to auto generate the part files for above object.

Is there a way around this? Preferably without the need for additional packages. Please advice.

For reference, the following would work but not keen to be naming fields in snake case to support this.

```
class FeatureResponse {
  List<Poster> trending_posters;

  FeatureResponse({this.trending_posters});

  factory FeatureResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) => _$FeatureResponseFromJson(data);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$FeatureResponseToJson(this);
}
```